# Problem when invoking Ansible from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

When i Invoking Ansible through Jenkins i have added the below script in my Playbook

```
- name: HELLO WORLD PLAY
  hosts: webserver
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - debug:
    msg: "HELLO......."
  - shell: echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

I am getting below error when i build job

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [10.142.0.13]: UNREACHABLE! => 
{
  "changed": false, 
  "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", 
  "unreachable": true
}
```

when I run this playbook through CLI it is running successfully
but I am not able to run through Jenkins as (i have already done the set up by pasting private key in Jenkins)

Comment: Perhaps run it with the `-vvvv` flag and add the log output to your question. The logs will hopefully provide more information to allow someone to answer.

Comment: okay let me try